# I'm a Teams administrator and I like to have a report of the changes of Teams user status for a specific user. How can I get it??? Thanks

Tags: office365, microsoft-teams

I'm a Teams administrator and I like to have a report of **the changes** of Teams user status for a specific user. How can I get it??? Thanks.

Comment: See whether this helps: In the left navigation of the Microsoft Teams admin center, select Analytics & reports > Usage reports. On the View reports tab, under Report, select Teams user activity. Under Date range, select a range, and then select Run report

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Please follow below link and check if its helps you in any way.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/teams-analytics-and-reports/user-activity-report

Comment: Hi Chetan, I didn`t have any answer :-(

Comment: @MarioSalguero -  Could you please share the exact real time scenario where you will need such kind of report?

Comment: Sorry for my delay to answer, this information is perfect for me, Thnks to Ken Lee for the answer and also to Prasad-MSFT.

Answer (score 1):

For more visibility, adding the answer from the comment section:

In the left navigation of the Microsoft Teams admin center, select Analytics & reports > Usage reports. On the View reports tab, under Report, select Teams user activity. Under Date range, select a range, and then select Run report.

[Reference doc link:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/teams-analytics-and-reports/user-activity-report)